# Is "Compasses" a typo?

Tags: word-choice

In the Wikipedia article for Freemasonry, it gave a picture regarding the emblem of the Freemasons:

[image]

The caption below reads:

> The Masonic Square and **Compasses**.
>   (Found with or without the letter G)

Just wondering, is "Compasses" correct? Shouldn't it be compass? I looked this up on several dictionaries, and I don't seem to find "compasses" when referring to a tool for drawing circles, only "compass". However, "compasses" makes sense, as it looks something similar to "scissors".

Should it be "compass" or "compasses"?

Comment: Just to point out that the instrument shown would now be called `a pair of dividers'. It is at least possible that the name changed when a pencil was attached in place of one leg, and so the instrument was not so obviously bifurcated.

Comment: In one of my high school math classes (ca 1963) the instructor quite firmly asserted that the instrument you used to draw circles was "a pair of compasses" rather than "a compass".  I don't recall anyone advocating "compasses" before or since, however (though I've completely blocked from my memory my freshman college drafting class).  No idea what current US school usage is.

Comment: The pivot is a modern convenience. In classical geometrical construction, the device falls apart as soon as you let go of it. This creates a technical distinction between what can be developed with classical tools and what can be developed using modern dividers which retain their span when you let go of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it is not a typo. I've looked up *compasses* in my Babylon English dictionary, and it says:

> compasses
>   n. instrument for drawing circles and measuring, calipers.

Additionally, *[Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/compass?view=uk)* states there is also *compasses* or *a pair of compasses*.

> compass
>   2) (also compasses or a pair of compasses) an instrument for drawing circles and arcs and measuring distances between points , consisting of two arms linked by a movable joint , one arm ending in a point and the other usually carrying a pencil or pen.

Comment: So, it's just an alternative spelling?

Comment: My understanding is that it's an alternative spelling which is [more apprehensible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compasses_%28drafting%29). I believe, without clear context, [compass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass) alone connotates navigational instrument that shows directions.

Comment: @Mehper: Context is usually pretty clear about whether you need a drawing instrument or a navigational pointing instrument. And as a point of reference, in my education (in Canada) I've never heard anyone refer to the drawing tool as "compasses".

Comment: Thursagen - it's is the correct spelling, since it is short for *a pair of compasses*

Comment: I remember way back in school, on the first day of geometry class, the teacher told us the supplies we would need, including "a pair of compasses".  Needing TWO of them seemed strange to me!  What, we would use one in each hand?  But then the teacher went on to explain that "a pair of compasses" was the long way to refer to that particular geometric drawing instrument.

Comment: Using compass in the singular, unless it refers to a device for navigation, still sounds odd to my British ears after 20 years in America.

Comment: @Kevin - agreed - UK usage is definitely "compasses" for the drawing or map-measuring tool, "compass" for something that points north.

Answer (score 6):

A *compass,* like *scissors, tweezers, glasses, pliers, tongs, bellows,* and *calipers,* is an instrument that is made up of two near-identical pieces that are attached to each other. Comparing it with these examples, it's somewhat surprising that we generally refer to it in the singular rather than in the plural. All three constructions: *a compass, a pair of compasses,* and *compasses,* are acceptable, although *a compass* is currently the general usage. As this [Google Ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=compass+to+draw%2Ccompasses+to+draw&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=10) shows, the plural *compasses* was formerly used much more often than it is now:

[image]

Comment: how has your Ngram distinguished between uses of `compass` to mean a drawing / measuring instrument, and uses to mean a navigational aid? If it didn't make that distinction it is not very helpful.

Comment: The Ngram compares the phrases **"compass to draw"** and **"compasses to draw."** It's really hard to fit the nativational aid into this phrase. If you have doubts about this Ngram, [the Ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=ruler+and+compass%2Cruler+and+compasses&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=10) for the phrases **ruler and compass(es)** shows the same behavior.

Comment: OK thanks, I had missed the small print on the ngram label: adding "to draw" should have helped to limit this to references to drawing instruments.

Answer (score 2):

I would always refer to the drawing instrument as "a pair of compasses" or more briefly as "compasses".  Compasses are, of course, grammatically plural as in: Those compasses are missing; I last saw them in yesterday's Maths lesson when they were in my satchel.  This practice, is grammatically identical to that used for many other single items that exhibit bilateral symmetry: (a pair of) trousers, tweezers, headphones, spectacles, speedos and so on.

When discussing more than one of these objects one has to revert to the unabbreviated expression.  In this context, one could no more refer to three compasses than one could state that one had bought three trousers.  It has to be "three pairs of compasses" or "three pairs of trousers".

The navigation instrument, however, is a compass; this is grammatically singular and it behaves conventionally and so the use of "three compasses" is unobjectionable.

Consequently, the caption "Masonic Square and Compasses" is correct.

Comment: Three of a kind beats two pair.

Comment: @tchrist that's not always true. Imagine having three shoes of a kind, but you have only two feet. What's the third shoe going to do? If you had two pairs, you could alternate them and make both pairs last longer than when you'd wear out one pair after the other. That's because you allow them to dry up properly. How are you going to do that with three of a kind?

Answer (score 1):

Historically the instrument for drawing circles and measuring distances on a map were referred to as compasses. It was the navy who introduced the name dividers to distinguish the instrument from the magnetic compass used for navigation.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it depends on the region: growing up in the United States, I had many compasses exactly like in that picture, and it was always "the compass". I've never heard of one of those called "the compasses". Sounds crazy to my ears. I've also never piloted a ship. But I have turned in plenty of so-so grade school assignments with diagrams drawn using my compass.

Comment: Hello @Johnny, welcome to the ELU stack exchange. Please list any possible sources you use so that the answer is credible.